# How can I access a videos folder on one of my PC drives from my Rails app in WSL2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So, I'm learning rails on PC with WSL2 (Ubuntu 18.04), I find it absolutely great, and as a new learning project I'm trying to make myself a personnal media center in Rails.

The app in itself works fine and I've been able to access the files through /mnt/drive/folder (mnt/d/moviesdb in this case). It detects the files on the pc, creates the videos in db, makes thumbnails  from ffmpeg, gets data about the movie with APIs, etc, etc...

The main problem is when it comes to actually playing the movies. Normally, the conventionnal way to display a video or something would be that I should put it in the "Public" folder in rails. For most apps that's pretty convenient because you rarely have a lot of videos. Except in this case, and that would consume a ton of space in WSL (+/- 2TB). Plus the fact that Windows doesn't claim back WSL free space so if I delete some movies to make some space it wouldn't do anything.

So the best solution for the videos would be to keep them on the PC while running the app on WSL2.

I've tried every path to the video and they all don't work. I then made some research and apparently, it's normal behavior, and that's because the < video src="" > field looks for something through HTTP, and not through the file system. And rails' video_tag is just an easier way to create an < video src="" > tag, it doesn't change the way it accesses a file.

So I figured I could use Nginx then to access these files. So so I tried this and made a new nginx server with a custom location to my PC, that I could then use as the URI in my src="" tags (like localhost/moviesdb/moviefilename where /moviesdb is my custom location).

But that didn't work, and I can't figure out why. Could someone please explain me what I missed or another way to achieve this?
I precise that putting them on aws or cloudinary or any other cloud services would cost way too much for this so that is absolutely out of question. And I kind of like being able to watch them offline. And I would very much prefer to avoid having to put all this inside my wsl2 virtual drive.

My nginx server is installed at default path in wsl2 (/opt/nginx). It seems to be working fine since I'm able to access my app through localhost/page without having to specify the port (Rails' Puma alone would want me to access it through localhost:3000/page)
Here is the mediacenter.conf file for the nginx server :

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;

  location /moviesdb {
    root /mnt/d/moviesdb;
  }

  location / {
    root /home/lachouffe/code/mediacenter/public;
  }

  rails_env development;
  passenger_enabled on;

  charset utf-8;
}
```

Thanks very much

Comment: If the src is on a different domain or port from the domain serving the page you need to use an absolute path such as `http://localhost/moviesdb/moviefilename`.

Comment: I was really hoping that it would be just that, but after trying, sadly that didn't do the trick.

Comment: What exactly is it that doesn't work? Have you tried using cURL or a browser to access the videos on the nginx mount directly?